Numeric string to datetime conversion in C# Winforms application
I'm getting a date value from XML in string (numeric). I want to convert the value like 72124 to 7/21/2024.
Then further I have to assign 7/21/2024 to a string variable.
Please help

I don't know if you or anyone you're working with is responsible for generating that XML, but if so, I'd recommend using ISO 8601 date formats (e.g. 2024-07-21) for data transfer.  (And possibly for your ultimate use case, especially if it's meant to be further read by computers, though if only for humans, then whatever makes sense for your use case is fine.)  More at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

When changing date representation, we can typically do it in two steps:

Parse string into DateTime
Format DateTime (with a help of ToString) into desired representation

I assume that date part is always 2 disits, e.g. 20524 is 5 Feb 24 otherwise we have an ambiguity: 11124 can be either 11 Jan 2024 or 1 Nov 2024
Well, .Net can't parse with Mddyy (due to variable month length while not having delimiters?) but we can fix it with padding:
string text = "72124";
        
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(
  text.PadLeft(6, '0'), 
 "MMddyy", 
  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Having DateTime you can format it as you like:
var result = date.ToString("M/d/yyyy");

Fiddle

As i can see you have 3 values combined in one string- day, month and year. Based on the example, i assume the opposite of what Dmitry Bychenko said about expecting variable length only for one of the date parts. I assume that if the month can be 1 or 2 digits, then the day and the year can be 1 or 2 digits also.
So i think that you should focus on how the XML is built. The value is not correct, because in this format it does not contain enough information to get the correct date in all cases. The value have to be with fixed length for day month and year or they have to be delimited

string numericDate = "72124";

int month = int.Parse(numericDate.Substring(0, 1));
int day = int.Parse(numericDate.Substring(1, 2));
int year = int.Parse(numericDate.Substring(3, 2)) + 2000;

DateTime date = new DateTime(year, month, day);
        
string formattedDate = date.ToString("M/d/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);        



As I can see, numericDate can be either 5 or 6 digits, imaing that you have numericDate = "123124", and in case of 6 digits length your code doesn't work. I assume that numericData always contains two digits date: 100124 otherwise we can have ambiguous values: 11124 can be 11 Jan 2024 or 1 Nov 2024

This answer would benefit from a bit of pre-amble, saying in words what assumptions it's making about the format, and/or when it will or won't work for various possible inputs.

As the commenters said this answer has some limitations, but it does layout a basic way to parse your string, id say to make this more whole and include edge cases, it would be easiest to set up a format mm,dd,yy (for example with the original string - 072124) but I dont know how you are getting your input
both day and month could be single digit which will mess this up, but without knowing how you get your input I cant do much more.
I hope you can modify this the last step to fully fit your use case
